# Cloud Computing: Who uses it

Tags: cloud

Who is using Cloud Computing like Windows Azure, Google Apps Engine, Amazone S3 ... and what are you using it for?

Why don't you use dedicated Servers or in-company infrastructure instead?

Do you know a Company that uses CC?

Comment: I've always wanted to use it to compute cloud simulations, myself.

Comment: I was going to answer "meteorologists".

Comment: -1 as this is Offtopic as even too broad and primaly opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Amazon EC2 for dev and qa. Saves us a ton of money since the load is relatively low. We are currently evaluating if we should move the prod environments as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if moving all my sensitive date to another company? How are your customers thinking about that?

Comment: With EC2 it's kinda like just moving your data to a data centre. You still have full control over your security just not its physical location, It's almost like a huge ESX server...

Comment: As long as whichever provider you choose have PCI DSS compliance in place, you should be good as it covers the processes involved in their infrastructure. Also, as Tim mentioned, we will have full control of how we want to implement the security.

Answer (score 2):

We use S3 to store our documents online. Cheap and easy. With [S3fm](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html) you can get your files online wherever you are.

Answer (score 1):

The company that I used to work for was doing actuarial calculations on a large in-house grid.  They embellished this with cloud computing for those peak times when the in-house grid couldn't handle a short term problem.  Pay for sufficient virtual machines, spin them up, perform the calculation, destroy the virtual machines.  It was a way to handle demand spikes without having to pay for the overhead of that hardware year 'round.

Answer (score 1):

I think lot of it for google app engine is speed of putting your work out there . If you are a two person company just starting out without the necessary infrastructure then app engine is a great option .
See google's statement [here](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2009/04/what-we-talk-about-when-we-talk-about.html) , too.

Even for medium sized companies it could help with extra loads on peak days. We use ec2 for releasing our product to thousands of sales team . In-house infrastructure just chokes on thousands of parallel downloads and it costs peanuts.